# If I use the sleep command in cron, will it affect other processes?

Tags: linux, cron, sh

I need to set my cron job every minute.

So I wrote the following crontab

```
*/1 * * * * /path/to/script/myscript.sh
```

```
#! /bin/sh

echo "start `date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`" >> /path/to/project/log/runtime.log

curl -s https://www.example.com/data.txt > /path/to/project/data/data.txt;

echo "end `date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`" >> /path/to/project/log/runtime.log
```

This time, my business parter said he wants this process will be run at 50 seconds per minute.

Cron does not allow to specify the time in seconds you know.
So I'm gonna use the sleep command.

```
#! /bin/sh

echo "start `date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`" >> /path/to/project/log/runtime.log

sleep 50

curl -s https://www.example.com/data.txt > /path/to/project/data/data.txt;

echo "end `date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`" >> /path/to/project/log/runtime.log
```

What I fear most,
Does this sleep process will affect other server processes or not ?

There are many other cron job running,
and my cron process will be the last of them to be executed.

```
*/1 * * * * /path/to/script/another-script-a.sh

*/30 * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/html/another-script-b.php 1> /dev/null

0 8 10 12 * /path/to/script/another-script-c.

*/1 * * * * /path/to/script/myscript.sh
```

If I use the sleep command to delay a process by 50 seconds,
won't it also delay other processes by 50 seconds?

Comment: Cron forks a new process so the job is running in its own space. There's no relationship between two different cron jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested two simple cronjob, they run on same time.

So I think sleep command will **NOT** affect other processes.

```
cd ~
mkdir test
sudo chmod -R 777 test
cd test
touch test1.sh
touch test2.sh
vi test.txt
```

```
*/1 * * * * /home/ec2-user/environment/test/test1.sh

*/1 * * * * /home/ec2-user/environment/test/test2.sh
```

```
vi test1.sh
```

```
echo "start1 `date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`" >> /home/ec2-user/environment/test/test.log

sleep 50

echo "end1   `date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`" >> /home/ec2-user/environment/test/test.log
```

```
vi test2.sh
```

```
echo "start2 `date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`" >> /home/ec2-user/environment/test/test.log

sleep 50

echo "end2   `date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`" >> /home/ec2-user/environment/test/test.log
```

```
tail -f test.log
```

```
end2   2020-12-25 14:29:51
end1   2020-12-25 14:29:51
start2 2020-12-25 14:30:02
start1 2020-12-25 14:30:02
end2   2020-12-25 14:30:52
end1   2020-12-25 14:30:52
start1 2020-12-25 14:31:01
start2 2020-12-25 14:31:01
end2   2020-12-25 14:31:51
end1   2020-12-25 14:31:51
```